# Alter Header Status Response to 410

Tags: 8, redirection, http-request

I have several urls with "/tag/" string; some of them have content and some of them don't, so they return 404.

How can I force them to return a 410 only for those that have no content?

I need a filter: has "/tag/" in URL and returns 404 -> redirect to 410.

I tried in theme_preprocess_html(&$variables) like this:

```
if ($pattern2){ //it has "/tag/" string
      $status = \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('exception');      
      if ($status && $status->getStatusCode() == 404){
          $response = new Response();
          $response->setStatusCode(410);
          return $response;
      }
}
```

It filters is working but nothing it's not redirecting to 410.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: This should be done higher up the chain than a preprocess hook.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, definitely higher up. When you are already inside of a 404 subrequest it is too late.

You could put the code in `on404()` of an HttpExceptionSubscriber, check the path and then replace the 404 with 410:

```
$event->setException(new HttpException(410));
```

See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/231263/47547