# How can I check the status code of a page?

Tags: 8

I want to check the status code of a page. I have tried with the following code in `hook_preprocess_page()`, but it doesn't work.

```
$status = \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('exception');
```

```
$status = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('_route');
if ('system.404' === $route_name) {
  // Omissis.
}
```

How can I check the status code for a page?

Comment: One method: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86559/how-can-i-convert-the-code-that-used-drupal-get-http-header-to-check-if-drupal?rq=1

Comment: Check this once, if it is to theme something specific for this page it can help

https://www.axelerant.com/resources/team-blog/customizing-http-error-pages-in-drupal-8

Comment: Did you check $status after executing the first line? This should be an exception object you can get the status code from `$statusCode = $status->getStatusCode();`

Comment: @4k4 – `\Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('exception');` returns NULL for 200 status code since there is no exception.

Comment: @leymannx, the original question seems to be about 404, but you can't check the route once you are inside of the subrequest, the only thing which connects you to the outside request is the exception attribute.

Comment: @4k4 – Would it be safe then to assume that if there's no exception the status code must be 200? (I'm currently working on [#2245767](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2245767))

Comment: This entire topic only makes sense in a subrequest caused by an exception and you want to change how the page is themed. There is no other case where this attribute is set.