# How can I add a dynamic redirect on a 404 hit?

Tags: 8, routes

I Created a site and URL that returns a 404 Not Found status on [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com) This creates a loss of link equity to the domain and negatively impacts the ability to compete in organic search results.

I wanted to Redirect the URLs returning a 404 status to the defined closest alternative, or parent category, to reclaim link equity from external domains.

Example: Suppose I am using URL **http://www.mysite.com/about/xyz/** and it return 404 so I wanted to create any module or system that smartly redirect to nearest parent path like **"http://www.mysite.com/about/"**

I am not able to find any specific documentation which would point me in the right direction.

Comment: Search 404 module?

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for your comment actually  it's a nice idea I tried that module but it does not fulfill my Exact requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a custom event subscriber. If the page is 404, grab the original URL and redirect accordingly.

To do so, create a new module ("response_test" in this example), with the usual .info.yml and .module file.

Then register your event subscriber in the module's services file... (see [EventSubscriber Example](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/simple-fb-connect-8x/eventsubscriber-example) for a full example.

**`./response_test.services.yml`**

```
services:
    response_test.response_subscriber:
      class: Drupal\response_test\404RedirectResponseSubscriber
      tags:
        - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Then create a class to handle the event

**`./src/EventSubscriber/404RedirectResponseSubscriber.php`**

```
<?php 

namespace Drupal\response_test;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;


class 404RedirectResponseSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
  
  public function onRespond(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
    if ($event->getRequestType() !== HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST) {
      return;
    }
    
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    if ($response->getStatusCode() == 404) {

      // Get the old path somehow
      // @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11047305
      $oldPath = ''; // Try using $response->getUri() or $response->headers->get('location')

      
      // Manipulate the $oldPath to remove the last part
      // @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51573313/5771750
      $redirectPath = dirname($oldPath);

      $new_response = new RedirectResponse($redirectPath );

      // Prepare a new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response and use
      $event->setResponse($new_response);

    }
  }
  
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::RESPONSE][] = array('onRespond');
    return $events;
  }
  
}
```

**Note**: This answer is partly based of Clive's answer here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/86622

Comment: Thanks @Chris :D really helpful for me.